# Relationship between $t$ and $x$ in $x'=f(t,x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a couple weeks into a course on differential equations. I've been told that it's more accurate to think of a differential equation $x'=f(t,x)$ as being determined by two separate variables, $t$ and $x$. So, my understanding is that while it is true that for a *particular* solution of the DE, say $x(t)$, the dependence of $x$ on $t$ is evident, it is more accurate to view $x'=f(t,x)$ as a statement about two separate variables.

Okay! So I'm holding $t$ and $x$ as distinct in my mind, and I go to solve a basic differential equation:
$$x'=-2tx^2$$
$$-\frac{x'}{x^2}=2t$$
And it's at this point that I suddenly remember a fortuitous fact: There *is* an implicit dependence of $x$ on $t$, after all! This allows me to integrate with respect to $t$, appealing to the chain rule and the FTC I: If $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $-\frac{1}{x^2},$ then $\frac{d}{dt}(F(x(t)))=-\frac{x'}{x^2}$ by the chain rule, and $\int{-\frac{x'}{x^2}dt}=\int{\frac{d}{dt}F(x(t))}=F(x(t))$ by FTC I (since $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous everywhere it is defined). So,
$$\int{-\frac{x'}{x^2}dt}=\int{2t dt}$$
$$\frac{1}{x}=t^2+C$$
$$x(t)=\frac{1}{t^2+C}.$$

It's only the very real dependence of $x$ on $t$ that allows me to use the chain rule and the FTC I to justify all that integrating. So, is the $x$ in $x'=f(t,x)$ truly a second variable? Another question is, Does it even matter? Like anyone, I can sometimes make mountains of molehills when I'm learning something new, and create difficulties for myself where none exists (as if things weren't difficult enough!). Is that what I'm doing here? Does it truly matter how I think of the relationship between $t$ and $x$ in the statement $x'=f(t,x)$?

Comment: I think the forms like $x'=f(t,x)$ or $f(x,x',t)=0$, etc. helps to organize the equations to form statements about them, and also give a general way of solving them.

Comment: Provided certain conditions are met, you can replace $dx/dt$ with $(dt/dx)^{-1}$ which means $x$ is not any more special than $t$. As for dependence, the equation itself makes the two variables depend on each other, so I'm not sure what the confusion is about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been told that it's more accurate to think of a differential
>   equation $x'=f(t,x)$ as being determined by two separate variables,
>   $t$ and $x$.

This may be because a lot of theorems require you to see if $f$ itself satisfy some hypotheses to guarantee uniqueness/existence etc. Now, $f$ *determines* a differential equation, but it does not care about the differential equation by itself, and that is what you have been implicitly told. Let's work out an example so as to make more precise what you are saying (or what you've been told) means.

Consider your example:
$$x'=-2tx^2.$$
I can consider the function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(a,b)=-2ab^2$. This function does not care about differential equations at all. However, when I compose it with the "lift" (for lack of a better name. Call it whatever you like.) of a differentiable function $x$, i.e., the map $\widetilde{x}:t \mapsto (t,x(t))$, we get your differential equation.

Explicitly, the differential equation is:
$$x'=f \circ \widetilde{x}.$$
The distinction I am trying to make is: when you are actually trying to solve a differential equation, the differential equation obviously couples $t$ and $x$. However, $f$ doesn't. We have that $f$ **determines** a differential equation, but is not a differential equation by itself. It is blind to it, it is a just a function of two variables. As any function of two variables, one is "independent" of each other.

Comment: This is  excellent! That second paragraph is really just what I wanted to know, but didn't know how to ask. It also answers another question I had: If $f$ *is* is a function of two distinct variables, then what is the relationship between it and the maps from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ I saw in multivariable calc? Thank you.

Comment: I do have one more question. You use the word "lift." You then say that we can of course use any word we like to describe it, but "lift" is such an evocative word, and I wonder: Is there a specific meaning you're trying to convey with that word, something that I'm missing that might give me additional insight? Is there a reason why "lift" might be an especially appropriate word?

Comment: @Ryan No specific meaning intended. The word is sometimes used to, given a path $t \mapsto \gamma(t)$, refer to the map $t \mapsto (\gamma(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))$, so it was just a name that came to mind for this reason. There is a thing, however, that can help you have more insight but I was afraid to give too much information (and also the one-dimensional case is a little less visual with this respect): $f$ can be thought of as a vector field. The vector field lives by itself, but the differential equation searches for trajectories which have velocities "in" that vector field.